# MongoEngine query unique attributes

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Can a mongoengine query return a list of objects that all contain unique attributes. For example if I have a database

```
[{name: Joe, age:22},
{name: Susie, age 22},
{name: Joe, age: 70},
{name: Susie, age:21}]
```

How could I query the database such that I want all objects with age <25 but only unique names. For example, I'd get the following result

```
[{name: Joe, age:22},
{name: Susie, age 21}]
```

or

```
[{name: Joe, age:22},
{name: Susie, age:22}]
```

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/ would work for the query -- try mapping it to mongoengine's capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You want MongoDB (and thus pymongo's) [cursor.distinct()](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.distinct) method.

Sample code would look like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

query = {'age': {'$lt': 25}}

conn = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
users = conn['database_name']['collection_name'].find(query).distinct('name')
```

Comment: OP is talking about using MongoEngine. MongoEngine does not have that method in the connection.